# Find similar string using similarity() function

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, traversal

Suppose a function `similarity()` which takes two strings in argument. If the two strings are similar, then it returns a number near 1, something near 0 otherwise.

So far I have a binary tree where each node contains a string as data. I want to create a function which will browse that tree node by node and return the word with the highest similarity.

**Attempt:**

Using @AshutoshRaghuwanshi's Answer, I got

```
void Tree::traverse(Node* rootNode, float& score, std::string& bestMatch, std::string& word)
{
    if(rootNode == nullptr) return;
    if(similarity(rootNode->data, word)>score){
        score = similarity(rootNode->data, word);
        bestMatch = rootNode->data;
    }
    traverse(rootNode->left, score, bestMatch, word);
    traverse(rootNode->right, score, bestMatch, word);
}

std::string Tree::browseTree(const std::string& word) const{
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw std::invalid_argument("The tree is empty!");
    }

    Node * currentNode = root;
    float score=0;
    std::string bestMatch;

    traverse(currentNode->left, score, bestMatch, word);
    traverse(currentNode->right, score, bestMatch, word);

    if(score>.90){
        return bestMatch;
    }else{
        throw std::invalid_argument("Word not found");
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem to work that well? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Hint, if your function returns 0.4 for the word "banana" and 0.45 for the word "bandana", how do you decide which one is the better match? Write a line of code which does just that.

Comment: OK now the interesting part. Suppose `banana` is the best choice on the left subtree and `bandana` is the best choice of the right subtree, what should the program do to find the best choice overall?  No wait, somebody has already given away all the secrets in an answer...

Comment: There are some errors but nothing that cannot be fixed.

Comment: Please elaborate "Doesn't seem to work that well?" because that is the only part which will decide the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
void Tree::traverse(Node* rootNode, float& score, std::string& bestMatch, std::string& word)
{
    if(rootNode == nullptr) return;
    float s = similarity(rootNode->data, word);
    if(s>score){
        score = s;
        bestMatch = rootNode->data;
    }   
    traverse(rootNode->left, score, bestMatch, word);
    traverse(rootNode->right, score, bestMatch, word);
}

std::string Tree::browseTree(const std::string& word) const{
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw std::invalid_argument("The tree is empty!");
    }

    Node * currentNode = root; //replace this line
    float score=0;
    std::string bestMatch;

    traverse(root, score, bestMatch, word);

    if(score>.90){
        return bestMatch;
    }else{
        throw std::invalid_argument("Word not found");
    }
}
```

This snippet of code will most likely work. Please replace the line indicated in the comment with the actual root Node of the binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

Tree traversal is never linear. You need a recursive logic. A simple example look like this:

```
void Traverse(const std::string& word, Node* rootNode, float& score, std::string& bestMatch)
{
    if(rootNode == nullptr) return;
    if(similarity(rootNode->data, word)>score){
        score = similarity(rootNode->data, word);
        bestMatch = rootNode->data;
    }
    Traverse(word, rootNode->left, score, bestMatch);
    Traverse(word, rootNode->right, score, bestMatch);
}
```

And then in your main code, replace the entire while loop with this code:

```
Traverse(word, root->left, score, bestMatch);
Traverse(word, root->right, score, bestMatch);
```

That should solve your issue.

Comment: Your function returns nothing. Thanks btw, I understand already a bit more. Is it a void type?

Comment: @notaprogrammertoday yes it is void, I updated the code.

Comment: I have modified my attempt in the question. Can you tell if it is fine. It doesn't seem to work for me. Btw, I think word must be in argument of `traversal()`

Comment: @notaprogrammertoday yes it might not be working due to missing `word` parameter. As I said before my purpose was to show the idea and not a well tested implementation.